# Describe REST service

Tags: xml, json, web-services, rest, wsdl

What is the most standardized form how to describe a very simple REST service producing JSON responses? Something what WSDL is for XML (but here WSDL would be an obvious overkill and not recommended).

Comment: See [Web Application Description Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Application_Description_Language) (WADL)

Comment: I've heard `WADL` is not a good fit either.

Comment: I've heard many things over the years. I don't believe all of them. Why would you characterize WADL as a poor fit (or where did you read it)? IME, it's fine for simple REST services and gets troublesome once you get really complex, but YMMV here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Responses from a REST service should be self-describing so having a separate description document would be redundant.

Comment: Even adding a "description" member to each JSON object response can go a very long way.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is one.  REST's lack of a WSDL-style service description is either a feature (greater simplicity, according to REST enthusiasts) or a major shortcoming (according to SOAP fans).

Answer (score 0):

The nearest equivalent I'm aware of is [WADL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Application_Description_Language)

Answer (score 0):

I came across this blog post which basically proposes using JSON for describing RESTful services. Thought its a brilliant idea and sharing it here: http://ttezel.github.com/blog/2013/02/23/stop-writing-rest-api-clients/